# split a sequence by delimiter in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Say I have a sequence in clojure like

```
'(1 2 3 6 7 8)
```

and I want to split it up so that the list splits whenever an element divisible by 3 is encountered, so that the result looks like

```
'((1 2) (3) (6 7 8))
```

(EDIT: What I actually need is

```
[[1 2] [3] [6 7 8]]
```

, but I'll take the sequence version too : )

What is the best way to do this in clojure?

`partition-by` is no help:

```
(partition-by #(= (rem % 3) 0) '(1 2 3 6 7 8))
; => ((1 2) (3 6) (7 8))
```

`split-with` is close:

```
(split-with #(not (= (rem % 3) 0)) '(1 2 3 6 7 8))
; => [(1 2) (3 6 7 8)]
```

Comment: What happens if your delimiter (`3` here) appears more than once? Same as the case when it appears only once?

Comment: In your example, 6 is divisible by 3 too, but why it is in the last partition?

Comment: @IvanGrishaev The question is asking for a split to be introduced *before* each multiple of 3, not after/around each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  I recently added [a function `split-using`](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-split-using) to [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo), which seems like a good fit here.  I left the `spyx` debug statements in the code below so you can see how things progress:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn start-segment? [vals]
  (zero? (rem (first vals) 3)))

(defn partition-using [pred vals-in]
  (loop [vals   vals-in
         result []]
    (if (empty? vals)
      result
      (t/spy-let [
          out-first               (take 1 vals)
          [out-rest unprocessed]  (split-using pred (spyx (next vals)))
          out-vals                (glue out-first out-rest)
          new-result              (append result out-vals)]
        (recur unprocessed new-result)))))
```

Which gives us output like:

```
out-first => (1)
(next vals) => (2 3 6 7 8)
[out-rest unprocessed] => [[2] (3 6 7 8)]
out-vals => [1 2]
new-result => [[1 2]]
out-first => (3)
(next vals) => (6 7 8)
[out-rest unprocessed] => [[] [6 7 8]]
out-vals => [3]
new-result => [[1 2] [3]]
out-first => (6)
(next vals) => (7 8)
[out-rest unprocessed] => [[7 8] ()]
out-vals => [6 7 8]
new-result => [[1 2] [3] [6 7 8]]

(partition-using start-segment? [1 2 3 6 7 8]) => [[1 2] [3] [6 7 8]]
```

or for a larger input vector:

```
(partition-using start-segment? [1 2 3 6 7 8 9 12 13 15 16 17 18 18 18 3 4 5])
   => [[1 2] [3] [6 7 8] [9] [12 13] [15 16 17] [18] [18] [18] [3 4 5]]
```

You could also create a solution using nested `loop/recur`, but that is already coded up in the `split-using` function:

```
(defn split-using   
  "Splits a collection based on a predicate with a collection argument.
  Finds the first index N such that (pred (drop N coll)) is true. Returns a length-2 vector
  of [ (take N coll) (drop N coll) ]. If pred is never satisified, [ coll [] ] is returned."
  [pred coll]
  (loop [left  []
         right (vec coll)]
    (if (or (empty? right) ; don't call pred if no more data
            (pred right))
      [left right]
      (recur  (append left (first right))
              (rest right)))))
```

Actually, the above function seems like it would be useful in the future.  [`partition-using` has now been added](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-partition-using) to the Tupelo library.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution because I can just call a function in the tupelo library now instead of rolling my own. It looks like it will run relatively quickly as well.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
(defn partition-with
  [f coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (let [run (cons (first s) (take-while (complement f) (next s)))]
        (cons run (partition-with f (seq (drop (count run) s))))))))

(partition-with #(= (rem % 3) 0) [1 2 3 6 7 8 9 12 13 15 16 17 18])
=> ((1 2) (3) (6 7 8) (9) (12 13) (15 16 17) (18))
```

Comment: 12 is divisible by 3

Comment: This output is correct. The question is asking for a split to be introduced *before* each multiple of 3, not after/around each.

Comment: This looks good, and is what I asked for; however, I don't know if I'll actually use it in my current quest, as the place I'm using it will be processing a lot of data and will be relatively performance-sensitive. This is a very elegant solution, but calling itself and using lazy sequences might create a lot of overhead in my current app.

Comment: That's reasonable. This was modelled on the core function partition-by, I retained the lazy operational semantics. Chances are the idiomatic approach to sequence processing is fine in most cases, only you know your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

and one more old school reduce-based solution:

```
user> (defn split-all [pred items]
        (when (seq items)
          (apply conj (reduce (fn [[acc curr] x]
                                (if (pred x)
                                  [(conj acc curr) [x]]
                                  [acc (conj curr x)]))
                              [[] []] items))))
#'user/split-all

user> (split-all #(zero? (rem % 3)) '(1 2 3 6 7 8 10 11 12))
;;=> [[1 2] [3] [6 7 8 10 11] [12]]
```